# Rewrite rules in .htaccess preventing wordpress to work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Just had this problem for the first time ever.

I have just installed WordPress in one of the folders on my root domain mydomain.com/blog/

Next discovered that some rewrite rules are preventing it from run on the domain.

I am on Apache with php5

the rules are as follows:

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.biz [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.co.uk [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.info [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.net [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.org [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.us [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.smydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Have now been stuck with this for over 5 hours, but cannot seem to find any answer anywhere.

Help Please!!!

Even coffee does not help any more :)

Comment: Looks like I am not in luck to get any answer today at all

Comment: Be patient. You say `"...some rewrite rules are preventing it from run on the domain."` ¿Why? Give some examples. ¿What kind of errors do you get, if any? Try to describe the problem more in detail. ¿What's the WP version?

Comment: basically, I have had to completely disable my htaccess file in order to install the wordpress in the first place, than I have re enabled it back and ever since I have done so, I am not able to log in to wordpress admin panel. I have tried and deleted several rewrites off my htaccess such as the one in my example above and than it starts to work, but clearly it will create a duplication problem for the rest of the site if I will completely delete those rules.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I have discovered the problem, for those of you who will run in to the similar problem, first stem is to disable your .htaccess file (remember disable not delete), then log in to your wordpress dashboard got to settings and change both urls to the `http://www.yourdomail.com/blog` then save it and enable your .htaccess. at that point you should be good to go.